# QuerySet results being duplicated when chaining queries

Tags: django, django-orm

So I am attempting to chain queries together. This is what I am doing

```
 queryset_list = modelEmployee.objects.filter(stars__lte=3)
 A = len(queryset_list) #A=2
 queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(skills__skill_description__in=skill_filter)
 A = len(queryset_list) #A=4
```

So with the above I am suppose to get two results but I am getting four. Seems like the results of first query are being duplicated in the second thus resulting to 4. Any suggestion on why the results are being duplicated and how I can fix this ? I was expecting to get only two items since it passes both the filters.

This is the model

```
class modelEmployee(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill, blank=True)
    location            = models.PointField(srid=4326,max_length=40, blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: can you please add `modelEmployee` defination and  what is`skill_filter`.

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: as skills is a `manytomany` field  employee instance that starts__lte than 3 which is 2 both have those skills. This is some thing like [ < User: 1 , Skill : 1 > , < User: 1 , Skill 2 > , < User : 2 , Skill 1 > , < User : 2 , Skill 2 > ] do you just want user id ?

Comment: What i want to know is why I am getting duplicates. Say the result of the first query is Adam and John. After running the second query Adam and John get added to the queryset again. Why are they getting added again when they are already present

Comment: If Adman and John has multiple skills they will add multiple time, better change the order of the filtering.

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

If you do a query on a `ManyToManyField` Django will perform an `INNER JOIN` which means there will be a row for every item on each side of the join. If you want to have unique results use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

```
queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
    skills__skill_description__in=skill_filter
).distinct()
```

See this [article](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/topics/db/examples/many_to_many.html) for some examples.